# I'm having problems with wtforms selectfields when i use a POST with Flask

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm pretty new to wtforms and flask and was messing around with selectfields and got an error. The form itself works just fine without the selectfield but with it I get the following error:

**Error:**

```
....fields.py", line 386, in pre_validate
    for v, _ in self.choices: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I see the selectfield so it's being rendered. I suspect somehow the id is not being validated properly on POST and is returning none. Or it has something to do with my selectfield tuple being returned ? Also the ID field I'm using is pulled from GAE's ndb automatic key().id() which is rather long and obnoxious. It could be the id length being used for the selectfield is too long ?

Googling hasn't provided much in terms of the exact problem so thought I'd post here. Relevant code below. If I'm missing something please let me know

**views.py code:**

```
@app.route('/new/post', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_post():

    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post = Post(title = form.title.data,
                    content = form.content.data,
                    hometest = form.hometest.data,
                    author = users.get_current_user())
        post.put()
        flash('Post saved on database.')
        return redirect(url_for('list_posts'))
    form.hometest.choices = [ (h.key.id(),h.homename)for h in Home.query()]

    return render_template('new_post.html', form=form)
```

**myforms.py**:

```
class PostForm(Form):
    title = wtf.TextField('Title', validators=[validators.Required()])
    content = wtf.TextAreaField('Content', validators=[validators.Required()])
    hometest = wtf.SelectField(u'Home Name List', coerce=int,validators=[validators.optional()])
```

**new_post.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1 id="">Write a post</h1>
    <form action="{{ url_for('new_post') }}" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <p>
            <label for="title">{{ form.title.label }}</label><br />
            {{ form.title|safe }}<br />
            {% if form.title.errors %}
            <ul class="errors">
                {% for error in form.title.errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="title">{{form.hometest.label}}</label><br/>
            {{form.hometest}}
            {% if form.hometest.errors %}
        <ul class="errors">
            {% for error in form.hometest.errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="title">{{ form.content.label }}</label><br />
            {{ form.content|safe }}<br />

            {% if form.content.errors %}
            <ul class="errors">
                {% for error in form.content.errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Save post"/></p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to set your choices *before* you call `validate_on_submit` as `form.validate` will attempt to validate the provided value (if any) against the list of choices (which is `None` before you set `choices`):

```
form = PostForm()
form.hometest.choices = [(h.key.id(), h.homename) for h in Home.query()]

if form.validate_on_submit():
    # form is valid, continue
```

Comment: How can you make it skip a specific field if you don't want validation on it ? I'm getting an error for date field with validators=[validators.optional()]

Comment: Worth asking a separate question about that with a minimal, reproducible example.  Someone should be able to help :-)

Comment: This is exactly my problem that solved by this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I was struggling with the same problem. Moving the myform.choices= whatever BEFORE form.validate_on_submit () fixed it !

Comment: Oh thank you ! I'm dealing with this error for an hour, that's exactly the solution to my problem !

Answer (score 6):

You should provide  `choices=[...]` argument, like

```
wtf.SelectField(u'Home Name List',
                choices=[(1, 'Label 1'),
                         (2, 'Label 2')],
                coerce=int,
                validators=[validators.optional()])
```

Comment: It appears you actually can't use the choices argument in selectField for dynamic choices, as illustrated in the documentation, wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/…, because even if your choices argument in select field is a query as in `wtf.SelectField(u'Home Name List', choices=[(h.key.id(), h.homename) for h in Home.query()], coerce=int)` that query doesn't run every time the form is shown.. so dynamically added instances of home won't appear in the drop down.. from what I've tested