# Flask Ajax post returns TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable for form data

Tags: ajax, forms, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms

I have seen multiple questions on how to implement an ajax post method in flask using wtf-forms and I have read the docs.  I am following [this post](https://medium.com/@doobeh/posting-a-wtform-via-ajax-with-flask-b977782edeee) as an example, but I receive a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.  I have validated the form data not using ajax and everything works fine.  I am not sure why it is not working for the ajax request.

my form:

```
class PathsForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name', validators = [DataRequired()])
    paths = SelectField('Path')
    cbt_id = HiddenField('CBT ID', validators = [DataRequired()])
```

My template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Edit {{ cbt.name }} </h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>{{ form.name.label }}</th>
            <th>{{ form.paths.label }}</th>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.name(size=32) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.paths() }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    {{ form.cbt_id() }}
    <input type = "submit" value = "Add Path"/>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            var url = "{{ url_for('process_cbt') }}"; // send the form data here.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                data: $('form').serialize(),// serializes the form's elements.
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)  // display the returned data in the console.
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); // block the traditional submission of the form.
        });
        // Inject our CSRF token into our AJAX request.
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ form.csrf_token._value() }}")
                }
            }
        })
    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

My flask route:

```
@app.route('/process_cbt', methods = ['POST'])
@login_required
def process_cbt():
    form = PathsForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return jsonify(data={'message':'Success'})
    return jsonify(data={'message': 'Failure'})
```

It looks like the csrf token is being correctly implemented and I have followed [the documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html) to setup CSRF protection.

Can anyone tell me why I might be receiving an empty form?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to put headers in your AJAX request that include the CSRF token, like so

```
                      headers: {

                        "X-CSRFToken": "{{csrf_token()}}"
                      }
```

Comment: Thanks Avian, but I thought that is what the ajaxSetup was doing at the bottom of the template.  I will give it a try though!

Comment: that now gives me a bad Request Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Woops! Forget about the application/json content type, just try with the CSRF token first. I've edited my original post - try doing it like that.

Comment: No, now back to `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: Hmm, I'll be honest with you, I'm unsure. I never use AJAX myself so I'm out of guesses.

Answer (score 0):

After way more googling than I'd like to admit I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15939584/4296857) and realized my problem was not so ajax based as it was a problem with the form validating.  I put in my choices dynamically so when it was trying to validate it did not have any choices to validate on.  I changed my view to the below and it all worked out.

```
def process_cbt():
    form = PathsForm()
    choice = request.form.get('paths')
    form.paths.choices = [(choice,choice)]
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return jsonify(data={'message':'success'})
    return jsonify(data={'message': 'Failure'})
```